# How do I measure web socket connection latency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to implement some way to measure web socket connection quality. I implemented latency calculation according to this post: [Measuring latency of Websocket Messages](https://ankitbko.github.io/blog/2022/06/websocket-latency/). I am using Socket.IO library and NodeJS for the server, though this is probably not very relevant.

The process is like this:

1. When client connects to the web socket server, it receives a response in this format:

```
{
  type: 'SERVER_TS'
  serverTs: Date.now(),
}
```

2. Client sends back the response in this format:

```
{
  type: 'CLIENT_TS',
  serverTs: packet.serverTs, // `packet` is data of the received message.
  clientTs: Date.now(),
}
```

3. Server receives a response of type `CLIENT_TS`, and sends back the response in this format:

```
{
  type: 'SERVER_ACK_TS',
  serverTs: packet.serverTs,
  clientTs: packet.clientTs,
  serverAckTs: Date.now()
}
```

4. Client receives message of type `SERVER_ACK_TS` calculates latency like this:

```
const clientAckTs = Date.now();
const { serverTs, serverAckTs, clientTs } = packet;
const latenctMs = (serverAckTs - serverTs) - ((clientAckTs - clientTs) * 0.5);
```

5. Calculated latency result is saved and steps `1 - 4` are repeated `N` times.
6. After `N` repetitions, latency measurements are summed and divided by `N`.

However, I am not sure if the implementation shown in the post is correct, because quite often I get negative values, which does not make sense. What am I doing wrong or what is incorrect here? Is there any other reliable way that to calculate connection speed of the client?

Comment: The link you gave also did -> `(server_act_ts - server_ts) * 1000`, you seem to have missed that bit.

Comment: @Keith Yes, server timestamps (`server_ts` and `server_ack_ts`) in their example are in seconds and needs to be converted to milliseconds. I use `Date.now()` which returns milliseconds.

Comment: Ok, thinking about this, if the last packet coming from the server takes a long while, then in theory the number could go negative.   So yes, I wonder if the calc is correct.   My gut feeling it should be more like ->  `(serverAckTs - serverTs + clientAckTs - clientTs) * 0.5;`   IOW: get the total latency server to client & client to server and divide by 2 to get the average.  Doing this, do the numbers look a bit better?

Comment: Both deltas measure the network round trip time (assuming the time to process the message can be ignored). They should be similar although they can vary with network conditions. The original calculation does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Keith Yes, the numbers look correct now.